# devexpress pivot grid send to attach excel mail

Tags: excel, devexpress, export

**How can I send mail DevExpress pivotgrid attached excel**

```
 fileName = "GridView.xls";
                    this.ASPxGridViewExporter1.WriteXlsToResponse();
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", disposition + "; filename=" + fileName);
                    Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not such a built-in capability. You need to export PivorGrid and send emails using standard methods. Here is a corresponding ticket in DX Support Center: [Q422021](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q422021). I see also that you are using a GridView exporter. You need to use [ASPxPivotGridExporter](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxPivotGridASPxPivotGridExportertopic).